How to Validate Firebase App Check on Android Emulators like BlueStacks?
We use Firebase App Check to protect our game from abuse and unauthorized access to our backend services. App Check is enforced for Android, and it works fine on physical Android devices.
However, we tested our game on BlueStacks (an Android emulator), and the results were inconsistent. Sometimes the game runs without issues, but other times it doesn’t work. We are unsure if App Check is supposed to work consistently on emulators like BlueStacks.
Our main questions are:
1. Does Firebase App Check support validation for emulators like BlueStacks?
2. If App Check doesn’t work for emulators, is there a recommended way to validate these environments? We want our players to be able to play on emulators.
Here is a response we received from Firebase Support:

To be honest, this is the first time I've heard about BlueStacks, I didn't even know this platform existed. As you can see in our documentation on Firebase libraries(https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries), BlueStacks is not listed as a supported platform.
Questions related to unsupported platforms or third-party libraries are beyond my area of expertise. I encourage you to post it on developer communities such as StackOverflow under relevant tags where fellow developers with similar experience can help you out.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
